# inserting a javascript variable into a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I am hoping someone can help because I am currently stumped.  I am using speedo popup to display a popup but I want it to always appear in the bottom right of the screen.  I found (thanks to someone smarter than i am) code to identify the pixels of someones browser and I have calculated, how many pixels I need to subtract in order for the popup to show up correctly and computed the variable for it but now I need that variable written into the speedo popup function so that it pops up in the correct place.

I need to put the values of the "h" and "w" variables to the right of the  "top:" and "left:" sections in the function statement below.

I hope this makes sense.  Any help is appreciated. Thank you

The code is included below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// JavaScript
function jsUpdateSize(){
    // Get the dimensions of the viewport
    var width = window.innerWidth ||
        document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
        document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
        document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
        document.body.clientHeight;

    document.getElementById('jsWidth').innerHTML = width;
    document.getElementById('jsHeight').innerHTML = height;

    var w;
    var h;
    w=width-580;
    h=height-270;
    document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML = w;
    document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = h;
};

window.onload = jsUpdateSize;       // When the page first loads
window.onresize = jsUpdateSize;     // When the browser changes size

$(function () {
    $.fn.speedoPopup({
        //htmlContent: "",
        theme: "metro",
        width:500,
        height:200,
        href: "http://delanceyplace.com/subscribe_iframe.php",
        autoShow: 1000,
        //left:956,
        //top:492
        responsive: true,
        effectIn: 'slideBottom',
        effectOut:'slideBottom',                
    });
});
</script>
```

So I figured out a solution but it seems to be just a little off - by using $(input...) it works just find for the width but when I use the code for the top, it the popup does not run.  with only the width in, it runs and responds correctly - as always, any help is appreciated.  thanks so much everyone. here is the new code:

```
// JavaScript
function jsUpdateSize(){
    // Get the dimensions of the viewport
    var width = window.innerWidth ||
                document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                document.body.clientWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight ||
                 document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
                 document.body.clientHeight;

    document.getElementById('jsWidth').innerHTML = width;
    document.getElementById('jsHeight').innerHTML = height;

var w;
var h;
//var th;
//var lw;
w=width-500;
h=height-200;
   document.getElementById('w1').innerHTML = w;
   document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML = h;

$(function ()
{
    $.fn.speedoPopup({
      //htmlContent: "",
      theme: "metro",
      width:500,
              height:200,
          href: "http://delanceyplace.com/subscribe_iframe.php",
      ///autoShow: 60000        // 60 Seconds
      autoShow: 1000,
      left: $("input[name='w']"),
    //top: $("input[name='h']"),
              responsive: true,
      effectIn: 'slideBottom',
      effectOut:'slideBottom'       
    });
});



};
window.onload = jsUpdateSize;       // When the page first loads
```

//  window.onresize = jsUpdateSize;     // When the browser changes size

Answer (score 0):

Can you specificy right/bottom instead of left/top?

```
$.fn.speedoPopup({
    //htmlContent: "",
    theme: "metro",
    width:500,
    height:200,
    href: "http://delanceyplace.com/subscribe_iframe.php",
    autoShow: 1000,
    //left:956,
    //top:492
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    responsive: true,
    effectIn: 'slideBottom',
    effectOut:'slideBottom',                
    });
});
```

Comment: http://www.agapastudio.com/products/speedo-popup-jquery-plugin/options it doesn't have a right or bottom option, but maybe it could be hacked in with css or script after the creation, or by editing the plugin's source

Answer (score 0):

$.fn.speedoPopup({...}); will only be called once. So you'll have to remove the current one (or update its location) after a 'resize' event.

I would call the jQuery plugin from within your update function.

Here's a trimmed down example that uses the Function.bind(...) to attach the width and height as the 'this' object.

```
function update() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    $(function() {
        $("#o").text(this.width + " / " + this.height);
    }.bind({width: w, height: h}));
}
window.onload = update;
window.onresize = update;
```

Comment: I see what you have done but I am a little thick tonight, how do I get those values into that function statement for speedo popup? really thanks so much.

Comment: @user3022448 - you simply replace $("#o").text... line with your jQuery. First create config object using this.width and this.height for those width: and height: parameters -- var config = { width:this.width, height:this.height, ... } -- and then -- $.fn.speedoPopup(config) --